# Need help to finish async form post and screen update using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I'm pretty much a jquery newb...I've almost got this working I think, let me know if i can clarify anything.

I have a screen displaying a list..let's call them affiliates. To create a new affiliate, a modal style pop up dialogue is used.

When the dialogue "Create" button is clicked, the form data must be saved (creating a new affiliate), the dialogue disappears, and the affiliate list updates without reloading the page

The jquery file at the bottom shows how I'm trying to do it now: trying to detect a click on the "confirm" button, get the form to submit using the data target property, and using the form's target property to know what container to update.

What is happening is: nothing.  The cancel button works, create button does absolutely nothing.

Also note that the "Create" button, which will act as the form's submit, is not located within the `<form>` tags.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing modals wrong but let's ignore that for the moment and focus on the async post and list update.  I've included my relevant code below to support my post.

--AffiliateListPartial

```
@model IPagedList<Acme.Business.DomainModel.Affiliates.Affiliate>

    <div class="items-list" id="affiliate-list-view">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Action("AffiliateDetails", "Vendor", new { id = item.AffiliateId })">
              //basic spans and razor display list in here..nothing notable
            </a>
        }
    </div>
```

The above partial view is contained within a full view, lets call it AffiliateList.  Nothing particularly relevant in there except that it is controlled by the VendorController/Affiliatelist method.

The VendorController.AffiliateList looks like:

```
public ActionResult AffiliateList(string searchTerm = null, int page = 1)
        {
            var userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);

            var model = (from a in db.Affiliates.ToList()
                            where a.VendorId == userId
                            select a).ToPagedList(page, 15);

            if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return PartialView("_AffiliateListPartial", model);
            return View(model);
        }
```

The modal style dialoque for creating a new affiliate (I'll just include the lines that I think are relevant):
_Modal.AffiliateCreate.Partial

```
<form id="affiliate-create-form" class="form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("AffiliateCreate")" data-acme-ajax="true" data-acme-target="#affiliate-list-view">
// multiple input elements
</form>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button name="close_modal"><span>Cancel</span></button>
  <button name="confirm" data-acme-target="#affiliate-create-form"><span>Create</span></button>
</div>
```

And the VendorController.AffiliateCreate method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AffiliateCreate(Affiliate affiliate)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(affiliate);
            db.Affiliates.Add(affiliate);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AffiliateList");
        }
```

And the .js file's relevant parts:

```
    $("button[name='confirm']").on("click", function() {
    var $form = $(this).attr("data-acme-target");

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("type"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-acme-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith(data);
        $newHtml.effect("highlight");
    });

    $(".modal_overlay").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".modal_container").css("display", "none");
    return false;
});

$("button[name='close_modal']").on("click", function(event) {
    $(".modal_overlay").css("opacity", "0");
    $(".modal_container").css("display", "none");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var $form = $(this).attr("data-acme-target");` is getting the attribute named `'data-acme-target'` of the button, rather than the form it's associated with. So then when you're using `$form.attr('action')`, you aren't getting anything back.

Since data-acme-target is an ID to another control that is the form you want to submit, use `$($(this).attr("data-acme-target"));` to get it.

Comment: $form = the button's target, which is  the id of the form...therefore, $form.attr('action') should be the form's action.  no?

Comment: $form is the button's target's id, not the control itself.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on         url: $form.attr("action"), and you'll see that $form is "#affiliate-create-form", the string, not the control.